# Is this edit too much?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

I've been dealing with a really weird [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545784/open-file-with-wordpad-in-java):

---

> [image: question_before]

---

I posted an explanation more than a solution that does not suits OP, after few comments OP commented:

> Actually there is a text file which i want to open from wordpad only not from notepad. But entering the file name as "abcd.txt" opens the file in notepad. How to open the file in wordpad – Tamannah Kumari 18 mins ago

Which, IMHO has nothing to see with original question, with this I answered with a simple `ProcessBuilder` and OP commented:

> Thanks! I got it – Tamannah Kumari 9 mins ago

Now. I assume `ProcessBuilder` solved OP question (he also marked answer as accepted).

Because of this I edited question (drastically) to clarify:

---

> [image: question_after]

---

- Is this edit too much even if it fits more to the OP needs?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The edit looks okay to me.  You found out what the OP was really trying to do and you edited the question to reflect that.  You did not invalidate any answers in doing so, so that requirement can be ignored.  You didn't put words in the OP mouth as the OP already said in the comment what they wanted, you just edited the question to match(which a lot of new users do not know they can do).

I do suggest that

> I want to read a file in Wordpad, i've tried

be changed to

> I want to open a file in Wordpad, I've tried

As the OP wants to open the file not read its contents(at least not in the program).

Comment: If you're going to continue improving grammar, please also change the comma after 'Wordpad' to a semicolon or colon (depending on your intent.) It's a nitpicky change, but English grammar is nitpicky.

Comment: @Jeutnarg And that is why I do not go to English.SE.  I am a native speaker and the rules are over my head.

Comment: If you *really* want to nitpick, then assuming the program in question is the rich text editor that comes built-in with Windows, its proper capitalization is WordPad.

Comment: @BoltClock Are you the picker of the nit ;)  And now you find more proof for me not to give english advice :)

Comment: @NathanOliver If english.se blows you off I wonder what francais.se and portugues.se would do to you haha